# I'm trying to build a music and video player, is there good support available in meteor js? Pls. suggest / recommend

Tags: meteor, video-streaming, meteor-blaze, audio-player

I'm trying to build a **music and video streaming / player** app, is there good support available in **meteor js**? Pls. suggest / recommend.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's both unclear what your question is and it seems an answer would most likely be opinion based, making it a bad fit for questions here. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is. Just use HTML/CSS/JS as you would for any platform.

Comment: Thanks Eliezer. The app I am trying to build is for both iOS and Android so that's why was planning to use Meteor. Idea was to use cordova to build it for the mobile phones. Any suggestion or references.

Comment: I would consider using React Native. But for video players for Cordova:
https://www.google.co.il/search?q=video+player+cordova&oq=video+player+cordova&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.3559j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8